# ng-number-picker component Angular8 - Count keep increment on `mousedown` and move away from the spinner button

Tags: javascript, angular8, numberpicker

There is issue with `ng-number-picker` component.

If we `mousedown` on the number spinner buttons and drag the mouse with press state (don't let it fire `mouseup` event) outside of the spinner then it keep increment/decrement the number.

[image]

How we can stop increment/decrement value inside the component when mouse is not on spinner buttons.

This question originally asked by Yogesh Kumawat on github.[component reference](https://github.com/wajdibeltaifa/ng-number-picker/issues/7)

Answer (score 1):

You can listen the `mouseout/mouseleave` event and call the `mouseUp` callbacks which will clear the timer that is set inside the library to increment the count value on long mouse press.

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.upButton=this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.up')[0];
  this.downButton=this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.down')[0];

  this.renderer.listen(this.upButton, 'mouseleave', ($event: any) => {
     console.log('onmouseleave', $event);
     let mouseUpEvent: Event = new MouseEvent('mouseup');
     this.upButton.dispatchEvent(mouseUpEvent);
 });

 this.renderer.listen(this.downButton, 'mouseleave', ($event: any) => {
     console.log('onmouseleave', $event);
     let mouseUpEvent: Event = new MouseEvent('mouseup');
     this.downButton.dispatchEvent(mouseUpEvent);
 });
}
```

I hope, it will help.